# Alternative of indexOf() method for multiple elements

Tags: javascript, operators, match, indexof

What is the alternativeo of **indexOf() method** for multiple elements and when used with the **&& Operator** not with **|| Operator**.

**Example:**

```
var fruit = 'banana,lemon,mango,apple';
if ( fruit.indexOf('banana') > -1 && fruit.indexOf('lemon') > -1 && fruit.indexOf('mango') > -1 ) {
   alert('found');
}
```

With **|| (OR) Operator** i found this solution: `fruit.match(/(banana|lemon|mango)/)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array and check if `every` element of the array passes the test:

```js
var fruit = 'banana,lemon,mango,apple';
console.log(
  ['banana', 'lemon', 'mango', 'apple'].every(str => fruit.includes(str))
);
```

For a regular expression solution, you can use multiple lookaheads:

```js
var fruit = 'banana,lemon,mango,apple';
console.log(
  /^(?=.*banana)(?=.*lemon)(?=.*mango)(?=.*apple)/.test(fruit)
);
console.log(
  /^(?=.*FruitThatDoesntExist)(?=.*lemon)(?=.*mango)(?=.*apple)/.test(fruit)
);
```

Note that `<regex>.test` (returns true or false, based on whether the string passes the test) might be a bit more appropriate than `str.match(<regex>)` (which returns a *match object*)

Comment: `(?=.*banana)` matches anything with "banana" in it, including "bananarama", so maybe `(?=.*\bbanana\b)` to match just "banana". :-)

Comment: @RobG this does not cause a problem for my use. it's what i need thank, you for these details.

Comment: Yeah, according to the [*MDN browser compatibility table*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Browser_compatibility), it's supported in Edge.